# Saving pics into SD card

Tags: android, sd-card

i am a biginner and watching some educational clips.when i run progressdialog comes on screen and suddenly it come out of running and it gives a notification"app stopped try again"
then i recieve this Error on android manitor of course i put firsts of that:

10-15 11:49:31.784 1306-1306/? E/EmulatedCamera_HotplugThread: createFileIfNotExists: Could not create file '/data/misc/media/emulator.camera.hotplug.0', error: 'Permission denied' (13)
10-15 11:49:31.784 1306-1306/? E/EmulatedCamera_HotplugThread: createFileIfNotExists: Could not create file '/data/misc/media/emulator.camera.hotplug.1', error: 'Permission denied' (13)
10-15 11:49:31.784 1306-1306/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
10-15 11:49:31.785 1306-1306/? E/CameraService: setUpVendorTags: Vendor tag operations not fully defined. Ignoring definitions.
10-15 11:49:31.807 1305-1305/? E/audio_hw_generic: Error opening input stream format 1, channel_mask 0010, sample_rate 16000
10-15 11:49:31.808 1305-1305/? E/AudioFlinger: int android::load_audio_interface(const char *, audio_hw_device_t **) couldn't load audio hw module audio.r_submix (No such file or directory)
10-15 11:49:31.808 1305-1305/? E/AudioFlinger: loadHwModule() error -2 loading module r_submix
10-15 11:49:31.808 1305-1330/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
10-15 11:49:31.809 1305-1305/? E/RadioService: couldn't load radio module radio.primary (No such file or directory)
10-15 11:49:31.809 1305-1305/? E/SoundTriggerHwService: couldn't load sound trigger module sound_trigger.primary (No such file or directory)
10-15 11:49:31.898 1296-1296/? E/SurfaceFlinger: hwcomposer module not found
10-15 11:49:31.913 1296-1296/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
10-15 11:49:32.720 1296-1322/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
10-15 11:49:32.722 1375-1420/? E/libEGL: load_driver(/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so): dlopen failed: library "/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so" not found
10-15 11:49:32.785 1375-1420/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
10-15 11:49:34.099 1304-1304/? E/Hyphenator: error loading hyphenation /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-cy.hyb
                                             java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-cy.hyb: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                 at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:455)
                                                 at java.io.RandomAccessFile.(RandomAccessFile.java:247)
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:118)
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:224)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:252)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:206)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:743)
                                              Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                 at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
                                                 at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:187)
                                                 at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:441)
                                                 at java.io.RandomAccessFile.(RandomAccessFile.java:247) 
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:118) 
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:224) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:252) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:206) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:743) 
10-15 11:49:34.103 1314-1314/? E/Netd: exec() res=0, status=768 for /system/bin/iptables -w -t nat -N natctrl_nat_POSTROUTING 
10-15 11:49:34.107 1304-1304/? E/Hyphenator: error loading hyphenation /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-da.hyb
                                             java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-da.hyb: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                 at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:455)
                                                 at java.io.RandomAccessFile.(RandomAccessFile.java:247)
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:118)
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:224)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:252)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:206)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:743)
                                              Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                 at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
                                                 at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:187)
                                                 at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:441)
                                                 at java.io.RandomAccessFile.(RandomAccessFile.java:247) 
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:118) 
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:224) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:252) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:206) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:743) 
10-15 11:49:34.107 1304-1304/? E/Hyphenator: error loading hyphenation /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-de-1901.hyb
                                             java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-de-1901.hyb: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                 at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:455)
                                                 at java.io.RandomAccessFile.(RandomAccessFile.java:247)
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:118)
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:224)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:252)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:206)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:743)
                                              Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                 at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
                                                 at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:187)
                                                 at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:441)
                                                 at java.io.RandomAccessFile.(RandomAccessFile.java:247) 
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:118) 
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:224) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:252) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:206) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:743) 
10-15 11:49:34.108 1304-1304/? E/Hyphenator: error loading hyphenation /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-de-1996.hyb
                                             java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-de-1996.hyb: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                 at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:455)
                                                 at java.io.RandomAccessFile.(RandomAccessFile.java:247)
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:118)
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:224)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:252)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:206)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:743)
                                              Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                 at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
                                                 at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:187)
                                                 at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:441)
                                                 at java.io.RandomAccessFile.(RandomAccessFile.java:247) 
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:118) 
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:224) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:252) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:206) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:743) 
10-15 11:49:34.108 1304-1304/? E/Hyphenator: error loading hyphenation /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-de-ch-1901.hyb
                                             java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-de-ch-1901.hyb: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                 at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:455)
                                                 at java.io.RandomAccessFile.(RandomAccessFile.java:247)
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:118)
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:224)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:252)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:206)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:743)
                                              Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                 at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
                                                 at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:187)
                                                 at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:441)
                                                 at java.io.RandomAccessFile.(RandomAccessFile.java:247) 
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:118) 
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:224) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:252) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:206) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:743) 
10-15 11:49:34.108 1304-1304/? E/Hyphenator: error loading hyphenation /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-en-gb.hyb
                                             java.io.FileNotFoundException: /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-en-gb.hyb: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                 at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:455)
                                                 at java.io.RandomAccessFile.(RandomAccessFile.java:247)
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:118)
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:224)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:252)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:206)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:743)
                                              Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                 at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
                                                 at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:187)
                                                 at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:441)
                                                 at java.io.RandomAccessFile.(RandomAccessFile.java:247) 
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:118) 
                                                 at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:224) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:252) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:206) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:743) 
10-15 11:49:34.108 1304-1304/? E/Hyphenator: error loading hyphenation /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-en-us.hyb

Comment: Can you show your code?

Answer (score 0):

I think that's not your application logcat, but it is belongs to whole system. by the way check if write to external storage permission is added in manifest

```
<manifest ...>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
...
</manifest>
```

and that's better to send your code for better solution.

Comment: so add your code and related logcat for better understand